# Android TCP communication is too slow

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

My TCP sender class is `TCPSenderTask` as client and I used service for TCP server.

When I try to send data, data transfer is too slow. I don't find the reason.

```
package com.example.sampletcpclient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.model.Order;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.TextView;

class TCPSenderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    Context mContext;
    TextView tv;

    BufferedReader reader;
    PrintWriter writer;
    Socket socket;

    ArrayList<Order> outgoingOrders;
    ObjectOutputStream oos;


    public TCPSenderTask(Context mContext, ArrayList<Order> outgoingOrders, TextView tv) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.tv = tv;
        this.outgoingOrders = outgoingOrders;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            socket = new Socket("192.168.2.3", 4999);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            oos.writeObject(outgoingOrders);
            oos.close();

            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result){
            tv.setText("Successuful");
        } else{
            tv.setText("Unsuccessuful");
        }
    }
}
```

and my TCP listener service as TCP server

```
package com.example.sampletcpserver;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.model.Order;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class TCPListenerService extends Service {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new TCPBinder();

    private int result = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;

    public static final String NOTIFICATION = "com.example.sampletcpserver";
    public static final String RESULT = "result";
    public static final String MESSAGE = "message";
    private static int FOREGROUND_ID = 1338;

    private String message;

    LocalBroadcastManager broadcaster;

    public static ArrayList<Order> incomingOrders;
    ObjectInputStream ois;

    public int counter = 1;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);

        incomingOrders = new ArrayList<Order>();

        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.service_logo);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("")
                .setTicker("")
                .setContentText("Service")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setLargeIcon(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 64, 64, false))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build();


        startForeground(FOREGROUND_ID, notification);

        Thread tcp = new Thread(new TcpServer());
        tcp.start();

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    private void publishResults(String message, int result) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(NOTIFICATION);
        intent.putExtra(MESSAGE, message);
        intent.putExtra(RESULT, result);
        broadcaster.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class TCPBinder extends Binder {
        TCPListenerService getService() {
            return TCPListenerService.this;
        }
    }

    class TcpServer implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(4999);

                while (true) {
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSock.accept();



                    Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket));
                    t.start();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
        BufferedReader reader;
        Socket sock;

        public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket) {
            try {
                sock = clientSocket;


                ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run() {
            String msg = "";
            try {


                incomingOrders = (ArrayList<Order>) ois.readObject();
                ois.close();
                sock.close();
                for (int i = 0; i < incomingOrders.size(); i++) {
                    Log.e("message", incomingOrders.get(i).getTableNo() + incomingOrders.get(i).getFoodName());
                }

                Log.e("packet", "received packet : " + counter++);

    //          Log.e("message", msg);

                result = Activity.RESULT_OK;

    //          publishResults(msg, result);
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Data transfer too slow when I try to send it. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You should construct the `ObjectInputStream` in the `run()` method of the new thread, not in the constructor, which runs in the accept thread and may delay other clients. There's nothing else wrong with this code that would cause slow transfers. It's a network problem.

Comment: I have done it but nothing changed. What do you mean when you ae saying network problem. Could you explain that?

Comment: I didn't say anything would change in a simple test. You would need multiple clients to observe any change. What part of 'network problem' don't you understand? Would you understand 'problem with the network'? Or maybe the network isn't as fast as you think it is?

Comment: The Java serialization format used by ObjectStreams is AFAIR very inefficient -and you will get problems when updating the data format. Furthermore you should use an BufferedOutputStream when sending, otherwise the transmission may get chopped down into TCP packets of just a few byte which will cause latency and reduces the usable bandwidth.