# Send all data from OutputStream in one packet

Tags: java, android, c, sockets, openssl

My app sends small lines of text (commands to the server) or 32 bytes chunks of voice data. Right now I'm just using the socket's `OutputStream's` write. However, the problem is that Android Java seems to like to send the first byte by itself. Example:

- Send: "Call Iron Man"
- Received: "C", "all Iron Man"

To work around this splitting I prefix each line with a "throw away" character #. So the previous example is sent as:

- Send: "#Call Iron Man"
- Received: "#", "Call Iron Man" --> "Call Iron Man" will be used and "#" is ignored.

The problem becomes when I want to send 32 bytes of voice, it is sent as one packet of 1 byte, and then one packet of 31 byte. These 1 byte packets waste a lot of data because of the TCP/IP overhead. According to [Sizing Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846077/size-of-empty-udp-and-tcp-packet) that means I will use (64+1) + (64+31) = 160 bytes for my 32 byte voice chunk when I could be using 64+32 = 96. That means I will be using 1.67X more LTE data than I should which (in Canada) will cost me a very pretty penny.

Is there a way to force all 32 bytes to be sent as one packet?

---

Here is the Android code for sending:

```java
int totalRead = 0, dataRead;
while (totalRead < WAVBUFFERSIZE)
{//although unlikely to be necessary, buffer the mic input
    dataRead = wavRecorder.read(wavbuffer, totalRead, WAVBUFFERSIZE - totalRead);
    totalRead = totalRead + dataRead;
}

int encodeLength = AmrEncoder.encode(AmrEncoder.Mode.MR122.ordinal(), wavbuffer, amrbuffer);
try
{
    Vars.mediaSocket.getOutputStream().write(amrbuffer, 0, encodeLength);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Utils.logcat(Const.LOGE, encTag, "Cannot send amr out the media socket");
}
```

Here is the C/C++ code for receiving:

```c
mediaRead = 0; //to know how much media is ACTUALLY received. don't always assume MAXMEDIA amount was received
bzero(bufferMedia, MAXMEDIA+1);
alarm(ALARMTIMEOUT);
do
{//wait for the media chunk to come in first before doing something
    returnValue = SSL_read(sdssl, bufferMedia, MAXMEDIA-mediaRead);
    if(returnValue > 0)
    {
        mediaRead = mediaRead + returnValue;
    }
    int sslerr = SSL_get_error(sdssl, returnValue);
    switch (sslerr)
    {
        case SSL_ERROR_NONE:
            waiting = false;
            eventful = true; //an ssl operation completed this round, something did happen
            break;
        //other cases when necessary. right now only no error signals a successful read
    }
} while(waiting && SSL_pending(sdssl));
alarm(0);
if(alarmKilled)
{
    alarmKilled = false;
    cout << "Alarm killed SSL read of media socket\n";
}
```

where MAXMEDIA = 1024 so there is definetly enough place for the 32 bytes of voice data

Comment: Unanswerable without seeing your code, but you certainly don't need to add junk at the beginning of your data. Your real problem is almost certainly at the receiving end.

Comment: OK added in both the relevant server and android code.

Comment: Your reading code appears to assume that only one read should be necessary. There is no guarantee in TCP about that.

Comment: Also see [Android TCP communication is too slow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30813864). Maybe [Silly window syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silly_window_syndrome)?